# Aptana Studio 3 And Svn - Manage files

Tags: svn, aptana, subversive

I installed Aptana Studio 3 and I set it to work with svn repository.
I'm able to checkout a project from repository in my local disk.

I would like to know:

- is it possible to see which file was changed and need to be commited,
- or which file has to be added?

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2014? Please, upvote it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aptana Studio uses [Subversive plug-in for Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/index.php) to support Apache Subversion. See it's User Guide [here](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/index.php).

You can view changes in ['Synchronize View'](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/workspace_synch.php); the page describes different status icons of so-called "synchronization states". You can also view the list changes in your working copy in command prompt, by running [`svn status`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) against your WC.

Read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/).